# Geo fencing not triggering notification

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, geofencing, android-geofence

Geo fencing working fine when there is English en language
When i change locale to fr pragmatically it stop triggering.

```
mLocale = new Locale("en");
            Locale.setDefault(mLocale);
            config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = mLocale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Android manifest

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".geofencing.GeofenceBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.myapplication.geofencing.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".geofencing.GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: i think you should test your device on another one and if it doesn't work on another one then i recommend you to show your code for how you register geofence and on catching it how you handle it because i think locale doesn't matter for geofence.